# Do regular Bluetooth keyboards work with Mororola Droid X running Android 2.3?

Tags: bluetooth, motorola-droid-x, external-keyboard

I remember reading couple of years ago that most (or even all) normal Bluetooth keyboards would not work with Mororola Droid X running Android 2.2. (surprisingly this [didn't seem to be covered on Android SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorola-droid-x+bluetooth))

Does anyone know whether the situation has improved since then by introducing Android 2.3 stock ROM, or better/more capable Bluetooth Keyboards? Or was the problem with Droid X hardware and thus unfixable?

Answer (score 1):

Download [BlueKeyboard JP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=elbrain.bluekeyboard.ime) from the Play Store. This makes it a lot easier to set up a bluetooth keyboard.

Here is how to set it up:

1. Install the app.
2. Then go to Settings > Language & Keyboard.
3. Check BlueKeyboard JP and go into its settings, and then into bluetooth settings.
4. Enable Bluetooth and scan for devices. Make sure your bluetooth keyboard is on also.
5. If you see it in the devices list, click it and then it'll ask you to enter a PIN. Just type 4 numbers (0000 or 1234 for example) and press OK.
6. Once you do that, on your bluetooth keyboard, type the same number sequence and press Enter and it should say your keyboard is "Paired, but not connected" on your Droid.
7. Go back and disable Auto Capitalization, select your keyboard in the Selected Keyboard tab and you should be good to go. To try it out effectively, disable your Android keyboard (or select the Bluekeyboard JP keyboard in the Input Method tab) and go into any app and select a text field and it should say that the keyboard is trying to connect in your notification bar. Once it does, try typing and it should work!

The Google Play page has some reviews from Droid X users saying it works just fine for them. That said, a lot of reviewers (on various devices) complain of unreliability.

Comment: How is this an answer for whether DrodiX problems with BT keyboard were resolved in 2.3 stock ROM vs. are they hardware limitations? In the second case the program won't help at all

Comment: @DVK I've added more info to Conn's answer.